# Asp.net Webform Validation for working

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Validation is not working in asp.net webform project for some reason event on a simple test page validation doesnt work, It always returns true and submits the form without validating.

Below is the actual test page i am trying to make it work to know the reason why it is not working.

Could issue be related to some reference issue or wrong library

Same file works in other project but not in this project, did i miss any file or reference.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="en_Test" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rf1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="vgForm" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return ValidateForm();" ValidationGroup="vgForm"  />

        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
        <script>

            function ValidateForm() {
                Page_ClientValidate("vgForm");
                if (Page_IsValid) {
                    alert('it is valid');
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    alert('No valid');
                    return false;
                }
            }
            </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Missing page directive?

Comment: This works just fine.. Dont see any issue. Do see anything logged in Browser console in dev tool?

Comment: @wazz : Works without page directive as well

Comment: Yup i see that now.

Comment: Fwiw, I see 2 WebResource.axd files in dev tools.

Comment: @wazz, Page directive is there, Problem i am facing is that it works in other project same code but  not in this project, not sure why validation is always true for client side only, when i check `if (Page.IsValid){}` from code behind it return false only client side it seems to be issue but what is causing this behavior i am not sure?

Comment: @shetty, wazz, I have never faced such issue with webforms, strange behavior not sure how to trouble shoot this